# Media queries in css being ignored

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Trying to implement simple media query for practice on notepad, but it doesn't seem to be picking up and I don't know why.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<style>

.heading {

    margin-left: 220px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  
  .heading {
    margin-left: 30px;
    }
    
   }
</style>

<h1 class="heading">Hello World</h1>
</html>
```

When I run this in the chrome browser in iPhone view, it ignores the media query and applies the first margin-left instead.

Comment: You don't have an opening `html` tag or a `body` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your viewport with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```css
.heading {
  margin-left: 220px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .heading {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<h1 class="heading">Hello World</h1>
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

Comment: Than you! this helped!